# @JsonIgnore serialising Scala case class property using Jackon and Json4s

Tags: scala, jackson, json4s

I'm trying to prevent one of the properties of a Scala `case class` being serialised. I've tried annotating the property in question with the usual `@JsonIgnore` and I've also tried attaching the `@JsonIgnoreProperties(Array("property_name"))` to the `case class`. Neither of which seem to achieve what I want.

Here's a small example:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson._
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.{read, write}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation._

object Example extends App {

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(Array("b"))
    case class Message(a: String, @JsonIgnore b: String)

    implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)
    val jsonInput = """{ "a": "Hello", "b":"World!" }"""
    val message = read[Message](jsonInput)
    println("Read " + message) // "Read Message(Hello,World!)

    val output = write(message) 
    println("Wrote " + output) // "Wrote {"a":"Hello","b":"World!"}"
}
```

Comment: Did you try annotating "b" using @JsonProperty("b") b: String instead of @JsonIgnore b: String? I believe that should solve this issue.

Answer (score 13):

Change your @JsonIgnore to @JsonProperty("b"). You have correctly stated to Ignore the property 'b but 'b has not yet been annotated as a property.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(Array("b"))
case class Message(a: String, @JsonProperty("b") b: String)
```

Comment: this is so weird, first annotate as a json string property and then ignore.

Comment: With Jackson 2.8.3, Scala 2.11.8, annotating `JsonProperty` separately is no longer required.

Comment: It is a good practice to name it with String since JsonIgnoreProperties is using the property name as string and that name might be renamed from some other context, breaking the "ignore".

Answer (score 1):

With `jackson-databind 2.8.6` and `jackson-module-scala 2.8.4`

```
"com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.6",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.8.4"
```

Only `@JsonIgnoreProperties` works fine,

Example case class as below where I'm ignoring `"eventOffset"` and `"hashValue"`,

```
import java.util.Date

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.{JsonIgnore, JsonIgnoreProperties}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

@JsonIgnoreProperties(Array("eventOffset", "hashValue"))
case class TestHappenedEvent(eventOffset: Long, hashValue: Long, eventType: String,
                             createdDate: Date, testField: String) {

  def this() {
    this(0, 0, "", new Date(), "")
  }

  def toJSON(): String = {
    val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
    objectMapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

    val data = this.copy()
    val stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    objectMapper.writeValue(stream, data)
    stream.toString
  }
}
```

#### test

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import spray.json._

class BaseEventSpecs extends FunSuite {

  val abstractEvent = TestHappenedEvent(0, 1, "TestHappenedEvent", new Date(2017, 10, 28), "item is sold")

  test("converts itself to JSON") {

    assert(abstractEvent.toJSON().parseJson ==
      """
        {
          "eventType":"TestHappenedEvent",
          "createdDate":61470000000000,
          "testField":"item is sold"
        }
      """.stripMargin.parseJson)
  }

}
```