# How to use camelizeKeys with hyphens

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I am parsing a json response from a web service which has some fields defined using hyphens. I want to convert these names to mixed case names in my scala case class. I thought to use the camelizeKeys stipulation but it doesn't seem to work. So for example say I have a json response like:

```
{"offset":0,"total":359,"per-page":20}
```

to be converted to:

```
case class Response(offset: Int, total: Int, perPage: Int)
```

and I do:

```
parse(str).camelizeKeys.extract[Response]
```

I get the error:

> Ex: org.json4s.package$MappingException: No usable value for perPage
>   Did not find value which can be converted into int

Comment: `.camelizeKeys` works on field names containing underscores, not hyphens. You could transform the field name(s) specifically (see, for example, [here](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) - search the page for "camelizeKeys"), or try to do a general string `.replace('-','_')` (on field names only, ideally).

Comment: Yes I had thought of that but was wondering if there was a more specific solution. You can't just replace all hyphens as this can cause problems with the data (date representations for example). See the solution below.

Comment: if you can use `json4s-jackson` instead of native json4s parser, maybe you can write something like `case class Response(..., @JsonProperty("per-page") perPage: Int)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654811/jsonignore-serialising-scala-case-class-property-using-jackon-and-json4s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around is to replace all occurrences of the hyphen with an underscore before parsing the text. So one could do the following:

```
parse(str.replaceAll("([a-z])-([a-z])", "$1_$2")).camelizeKeys.extract[Response]
```

But this solution is limited as with complicated data structures it may not work; you could end up corrupting the data returned if any field values contains such a pattern. So a more complete solution was to write my own replaceAll function:

```
def replaceAll(str: String, regex: String)(f: String => String) = {
    val pattern = regex.r
    val (s, i) = (("", 0) /: pattern.findAllMatchIn(str)) { case ((s, i), m) =>
        (s + str.substring(i, m.start) + f(m.toString), m.end)
    }
    s + str.substring(i)
}
```

and apply it to my json string thus:

```
replaceAll(str, "\"[0-9a-z\\-]*\":")(_.replace('-', '_'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the hyphens by underscores as below.

```scala
def replaceHyphens(value: JValue): JValue = {
    value.transformField {
        case JField(name, x) => JField(name.replaceAll("-", "_"), x)
    }
}
```

This function is implemented by referring to [rewriteJsonAST](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/20de4d990bc9eabe3eb25ca30d539af44799fac7/core/src/main/scala/org/json4s/MonadicJValue.scala#L420) in json4s

```
replaceHyphens(parse(str)).camelizeKeys.extract[Response]
```